How can it be stabilized for Vuforia Ground Plane Tracking in Native Apps(2)
Please allow me to post again. Thank you for your advice the other day.
ISSUE:
We are using Vuforia in our native app. We recently upgraded from version 9.1.7 to 10.22.5.
In Vuforia version 9.1.7, the model is fixed to the ground and appears naturally with respect to human movement.
However, in version 10.22.5, the model does not appear to be fixed to the ground.
We are having trouble with a Vuforia version upgrade that we have tried which has changed our display significantly.
A sample video of Vuforia version 10.22.5 is attached.
（I am attaching a gif file because I could not upload a video (mp4).）
Sample Video01
Sample Video02
Regarding the program, it is being constructed with reference to:
・Ground Plane API Overview
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/environments/ground-plane-api-overview
・Pose Status and Status Info Native
https://developer.vuforia.com/getting-started/pose-status-and-status-info-native#area-targets-and-anchors-pose-status-and-status-info
Since the status for Ground Plane (Anchors)　is only showing VU_OBSERVATION_POSE_STATUS_EXTENDED_TRACKED,
is it possible that the accuracy is reduced due to the tracking being simulated?
I would appreciate any assistance you can provide if you have a good solution.

Is this a Unity app or a native app? Have you looked at this troubleshooting guide? https://developer.vuforia.com/library/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-your-app

Thank you for your comment. This is a native app. We have tried the troubleshooting steps you shared before. Given that the status for the Ground Plane (Anchors) is only VU_OBSERVATION_POSE_STATUS_EXTENDED_TRACKED, could the accuracy be reduced due to being in a pseudo-tracking state? If you know of any effective methods to address this issue, I would greatly appreciate your advice. Please let us know if there is any other information we should provide.

From this information here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/getting-started/pose-status-and-status-info-native#area-targets-and-anchors-pose-status-and-status-info the status VU_OBSERVATION_POSE_STATUS_EXTENDED_TRACKED is the "normal" status indicating everything is working as expected. There might be a difference in coordinate systems between Engine versions. Have you looked at the native sample code here https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples ? To help further you should share the code you use to process the anchor observations.
